# Can I have carrierwave mount_uploader only apply to certain data in a db column and not others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, carrierwave

In my rails app I have `items` that have many `values`. Users can change the values on the items. I have the values categorised into 3 types or `value_types`. 1 is one or two words, 2 is a long slab of text, and 3 is an image. The user has an input field displayed for value type 1, a text field for 2 and file field if `value_type` is 3.

I've just implemented carrierwave and it works for the image upload but now if I enter any information into the `value` column that isn't an image file it doesn't work. My app is hard coded this way and I would have to change a lot of things to split image value types into a separate column.

I though maybe it would be possible to add something like an if statement in the model so `mount_uploader` only applied to values that have the `value_type == 3`. I came up with the code below but although it doesn't throw any errors it also doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader, if: 'value_type == 3'
```

I also tried this which works for non image types but saves the images as `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe74b2e2e28>` instead of `image-name.png`

```
if :value_type == 3
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader
else
end
```

Anyone know of a way for me to have carrierwave `mount_uploader` only apply to the `value` if the `value_type` is equal to 3?

Comment: Rob, Did you solve this issue? If yes, how?

Comment: @ashr81 It was so long ago I can't remember. Sorry